# What creature sounds like an adult human man saying "Hrmmm"?

Tags: animal-identification

**Geography**

Western Rockies, 6000 feet elevation.

**Time of day**

This thing only shows up at nightfall.  It is gone by early morning even when it is still pitch black outside.

**Sound**

It sounds like an adult male human saying "Hrmmmmm"  as if it were displeased with my presence.

**Am I hearing things**

A family member heard this as well.  I wasn't actually going to tell them because it would have spooked them.  They told me after I had already heard it twice.  We hear it every night at nightfall.  I am going to try to record the audio.

**Position**

It is always behind me at my level.  I turn around, wearing a powerful headlamp and can not see it.  I also have a 100k lumen LED flashlight.  I can not find it.  The sound does not move position and I can not hear wings.

**What might it eat?**

There are moths, lots of them.  I have been getting rid of the moths to test that theory.  There are also field mice, grasshoppers, crickets, grass snakes and marmots.  Most of the marmots have been in their holes and they stay very clear of humans.

**Hypothesis**

None.  I have been in the wilderness all throughout the U.S.  I have never heard an animal capable of making this sound.  I have heard MockingJays and Starlings mimic other creatures, but they can't make the bass/baritone sounds like a human.  There are horses near by, but they can't make this sound, certainly not in between the house and my vehicle.  The mountain lions, bears and elk don't go anywhere near my home.

Any ideas?

---

I should add that it also knows which way I am facing.  It will only make that sound behind me, never beside or in front of me.  It also knows if my headlamp is on.  I have to turn off my headlamp to hear the sound.

Comment: You say there *are* horses nearby, and horses make non-vocalized snorting sounds with their nostrils.

Comment: This is a very vocalized and distinct "Hrmmm" identical to a human doing it.  I am going to sit out tonight and see if I can capture it on camera or with the limited audio equipment I have.  More of my equipment will show up in a couple weeks.

Comment: Any chance its a moth against a window or bush, being amplified? Mountain goats?

Comment: any chances with owls?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzbmj6vuMw8

Comment: "I am going to try to record the audio." That sounds if not extremely helpful at least intriguing!

Comment: I have not been able to hear it again, but it MIGHT be a great grey owl.  I've never heard them make that sound and there are no examples on youtube that come even close, but it is the only owl I have seen on my property.  It shouldnt even be in this area.   They do not like being around people.  It is for sure the biggest owl I have ever seen.

Comment: Sounds like it's an "an adult male human saying "Hrmmmmm" as if [he] were displeased with [your] presence. Say hello. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're describing the call of the Great Grey Owl, whose range includes the western Rockies. [Here is what it sounds like](https://youtu.be/Jzbmj6vuMw8?t=250).

Comment: That is actually really close to what I heard.   What I heard sounded more like a human trying to make that sound, but maybe the owl on my property has figured out how to do this.  I think I scared it off with a flashlight by mistake.  I did see the X between the eyes so I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Roe Deer sound like dogs barking or babies screaming at night to mark their territory.

A "Hrmmm"! Might be a goat considering you are in the Mountains. But most likely it's a bird.

Crows are pretty vocal and in my area they sound like Radio signals. Very alien like cloaking sound. Almost like clicking but deeper and it ecoes very far. But that's during the day.

Which birds are nocturnal in your area? Owl maybe?

Does it remind of this weird Raven noise?
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NVeUtSSrkG0

Edit:
It's plausible to be a Raven as they can mimic many sounds, including humans: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AfsnHVaScjg&noapp=1